# Sqlite use 'in' or '=' in WHERE x IN (Select ...)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query for a sqlite application

```
SELECT * FROM compounds c JOIN spectraData s ON c.rowid = s.compoundID 
WHERE s.compoundID = (SELECT compoundID FROM spectraData WHERE mz = 171);
```

With two tables structured as

```
CREATE TABLE compounds (name VARCHAR(200), cas VARCHAR(15), formula VARCHAR(100), peakProduct INT)
CREATE TABLE spectraData (compoundID INT, mz INT, intensity INT)
```

with 101,595 and 20,985,713 rows respectively and a index:

```
CREATE INDEX mz_sort ON spectraData ("mz")
```

When I use the query with `s.compoundID = (SELECT ...` it takes 5.6 ms, but if the code is changed to `s.compoundID IN (SELECT ...` it goes up to 44.8 ms. Why is there such a big difference between the two?

I thought the `in` command would be faster than `=`. Any thoughts on why this would be the case? Is there another way to structure my query?

Comment: The commands are not equivalent, and should be returning different result sets.  The second is returning the *correct* result set.  The first is converting the result of the SELECT statement to a scalar value and returning a single record.

Comment: @LarryLustig I see, it was just returning the first compoundID it found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `s.compoundID IN (SELECT compoundID ...)`, the database executes the subquery and uses *all* returned values to compare against `s.compoundId`.
Assuming that the subquery returns five values, this is the same as if you had written something like `s.compoundID IN (11, 22, 33, 44, 55)`.

When you use `s.compoundID = (SELECT compoundID ...)`, the database executes the subquery, but takes only the *first* value returned.
This is the same as if you had written something like `s.compoundID = 11`.

Answer (score -1):

i use sql tool to explain the two sql.
found that :
when use =,it displays [image]

when use in,it displays [image]

i tried look for some detail from mysql_dev_doc,but i found nothing.

but according to the explained result, i guess that, when use "=" ,it will process the subquery once for every line of table compounds comparing,but when use "in",just process the subquery once,and use the subquery result to find data from table compounds.

am i right?
i hope so...haha

Comment: That MySQL uses a dependent subquery is a MySQL optimizer bug which has nothing to do with SQLite.

Comment: SQLite executes these queries [differently](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/512e0/3).